# Create promises from 2D array in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

To import several unrelated csv files into mongodb, I parse the files client side and then send "import maps" to node. There they get passed to a function to upsert them to mongoose/mongodb. The function works and is similar to the following (less the promises parts).

```
Import.prototype.saveImport = function (importArray) {
    var writes = []; //promises
    for (var i = 0; i < importArray.length; i++) { //loop models
        var Model = mongoose.model(importArray[i].model);
        for (var j = 0; j < importArray[i].objects.length; j++) { //loop objects
            writes.push(function () {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    var obj = importArray[i].objects[j];

                    var searchObj = {};
                    for (var k = 0; k < importArray[i].ImportIndex.length; k++) {
                        var index = importArray[i].ImportIndex[k];
                        searchObj[index] = obj[index];
                    }

                    Model.update(searchObj, {
                        $set: obj
                    }, {
                        upsert: true
                    }, function (err, raw) {
                        if (err)
                            console.log(err);
                        resolve();
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    }
    Promise.all(writes)
        .then(function () {
            console.log('all done');
        })
        .catch(console.error);
};
```

This function does not work for several reasons, it is just to illustrate what I am trying to do. I need some way to wait for all mongodb writes to complete so I can send a reply to the client. But I am at a loss on how to achieve it.

Promises seemed like the simplest way to do this. But how do I add promises inside the second loop so I have access to the outer variables? I am open to other options though preferably without other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

one way could be that you can create a new promise from promise.all for every row and push it back to new array and call promise.all.

```
for (var i = 0; i < write.length; i++) {
    promiseArr.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Promise.all(writes[i])
        .then(resolve)
        .catch(reject);
    }));
}

Promise.all(promiseArr)
.then(function () {
    console.log('all done');
})
.catch(console.error);
```